# XeLaTeX: Letterspacing with swashes

Tags: xetex, fontspec, letterspacing, ebgaramond

I'm trying to use XeLaTeX to typeset a word in EB Garamond, and I want only two of the letters in the word to have swashes.  However, the swashed characters screw up the letterspacing:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[LetterSpace=40]{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
% No swashes, correct letterspacing:
\emph{ANAGRAMME.}

% Two swashes, incorrect letterspacing:
\emph{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+swsh}A\addfontfeature{RawFeature=-swsh}NA\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+swsh}G\addfontfeature{RawFeature=-swsh}RAMME.}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of the example code]

How can I make the letterspacing consistent around the swashed glyphs?

Comment: Letter spacing doesn't work across font changes.

Comment: It is notable that this ***is*** possible with pdfTeX if the fonts are set up appropriately to support it. That is, if swashes are realised as ligatures, you can use the letter spacing facilities of `microtype` to do this because no font change is required. [There is a price in terms of control when you switch from traditional TeX fonts to the use of system fonts.]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Letter spacing can't work across font changes. You have to emulate it with an explicit kern. Since the font is at 12pt, `LetterSpacing=40` corresponds to adding a 4.8pt kern between letters.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[LetterSpace=40]{EB Garamond}
\begin{document}
% No swashes
\emph{ANAGRAMME}

% Two swashes
\emph{\addfontfeature{RawFeature=+swsh}A\kern4.8pt
  \addfontfeature{RawFeature=-swsh}NA\kern4.8pt
  \addfontfeature{RawFeature=+swsh}G\kern4.8pt
  \addfontfeature{RawFeature=-swsh}RAMME}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  In my document I may need to do this with texts of various font sizes and letterspacing values.  What's the formula for calculating the kerning in the general case?

Comment: @Psychonaut `<letter spacing factor> * <font size>/10`

Comment: I didn’t try this example until today, so I don’t know how TeX Live 2014 behaved, but at least in 2015, `luatex` seems to get letterspacing right across these font changes.  That’s surprising but very welcome!  `xetex`, which the OP asked about, still needs the explicit kerns.